# CIFS VFS: Close unmatched open client: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS server: TrueNAS-12.0-U1.1 mount

Tags: mount, samba, cifs

Running an Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS with a cifs mount pointing to a TrueNAS-12.0-U1.1 server and sometimes I get the following error in dmesg: CIFS VFS: Close unmatched open This generally relates to an Interrupted System Call in the application error logs

```
  at System.IO.FileStatus.EnsureStatInitialized (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] path, System.Boolean continueOnError) [0x00039] in <d13c8b563008422a8c5aaec0a74089cc>:0 
  at System.IO.FileStatus.GetAttributes (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] path, System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fileName) [0x00000] in <d13c8b563008422a8c5aaec0a74089cc>:0 
  at System.IO.FileSystemInfo.get_Attributes () [0x0001c] in <d13c8b563008422a8c5aaec0a74089cc>:0 
  at System.IO.FileInfo.get_Length () [0x00000] in <d13c8b563008422a8c5aaec0a74089cc>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileInfo.get_Length()
  at NzbDrone.Common.Disk.DiskProviderBase.GetFileSize (System.String path) [0x00077] in C:\BuildAgent\work\5d7581516c0ee5b3\src\NzbDrone.Common\Disk\DiskProviderBase.cs:174 
  at NzbDrone.Core.MediaFiles.EpisodeImport.Aggregation.AggregationService.Augment (NzbDrone.Core.Parser.Model.LocalEpisode localEpisode, System.Boolean otherFiles) [0x0004b] in C:\BuildAgent\work\5d7581516c0ee5b3\src\NzbDrone.Core\MediaFiles\EpisodeImport\Aggregation\AggregationService.cs:53 
  at NzbDrone.Core.MediaFiles.EpisodeImport.Manual.ManualImportService.Execute (NzbDrone.Core.MediaFiles.EpisodeImport.Manual.ManualImportCommand message) [0x0017a] in C:\BuildAgent\work\5d7581516c0ee5b3\src\NzbDrone.Core\MediaFiles\EpisodeImport\Manual\ManualImportService.cs:284 
  at NzbDrone.Core.Messaging.Commands.CommandExecutor.ExecuteCommand[TCommand] (TCommand command, NzbDrone.Core.Messaging.Commands.CommandModel commandModel) [0x000f6] in C:\BuildAgent\work\5d7581516c0ee5b3\src\NzbDrone.Core\Messaging\Commands\CommandExecutor.cs:95 
  at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object.CallSite.Target(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure,System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite,NzbDrone.Core.Messaging.Commands.CommandExecutor,object,NzbDrone.Core.Messaging.Commands.CommandModel)
  at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid3[T0,T1,T2] (System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2) [0x00035] in <c5bd4c865d5d48d3b3ebe4d522fd6bd7>:0 
  at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object.CallSite.Target(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure,System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite,NzbDrone.Core.Messaging.Commands.CommandExecutor,object,NzbDrone.Core.Messaging.Commands.CommandModel)
  at NzbDrone.Core.Messaging.Commands.CommandExecutor.ExecuteCommands () [0x00027] in C:\BuildAgent\work\5d7581516c0ee5b3\src\NzbDrone.Core\Messaging\Commands\CommandExecutor.cs:41
```

I don't see any errors on the Truenas side when this happens, but not sure what debugging level I should really be at.

Cifs volume is mounted with
`//10.0.103.4/media on /mnt/media type cifs (rw,relatime,vers=3.0,cache=strict,username=downloads,uid=1005,forceuid,gid=1005,forcegid,addr=10.0.103.4,file_mode=0775,dir_mode=0775,soft,nounix,serverino,mapposix,rsize=4194304,wsize=4194304,bsize=1048576,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1)`

I have also tried vers=2.1 but with the same outcome.

Any suggestions on what might be causing this?